# How to Insert a character at certain point java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm getting data from a excel sheet.

The data format in the excel is like "70142012" , "7032014" , "641252013".

It is not always the same quantity of numbers.

And i need to insert a " / " before the last 4 numbers.

it has to be like "7014/2012" , "703/2014" , "64125/2013".

this is part of my code...

```
String xlPath = "C:/Users/P_701362/Desktop/bancosiconv.xls";

    int xlRows, xlCols;

    String localArray[][] = new String[50000][3];

    WebDriver oWD = new ChromeDriver();

    String strNumeroSiconv;

    strNumeroSiconv = localArray[i][0];

    oWD.findElement(By.id("consultarNumeroProposta")).sendKeys(strNumeroSiconv);
```

---

the string strNumeroSiconv that needs to be send with the "/" before the last 4 numbers..

how can i do this?

i'm using selenium by the way.

thanks.

Comment: Did you make any attempt to Google this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `StringBuilder` like this: or you can use `StringBuffer` but for single threaded context `StringBuilder` is always better option since it is not `synchronized` so it will be faster.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("7017642012");
        sb.insert((sb.length()-4), '/');
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

output :

```
701764/2012
```

As an array of `StringBuilder`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder []sb=new StringBuilder[5];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
          sb[i]=new StringBuilder("98345834"+i);
          sb[i].insert((sb[i].length()-4), '/');
          System.out.println(sb[i]);
        }
    }
```

output :

```
98345/8340
98345/8341
98345/8342
98345/8343
98345/8344
```

Comment: I recommend a `StringBuilder` instead for better performance in single-threaded contexts.

Comment: but can i use Stringbuilder with array?
fetching excel data?

Comment: @BrunoSousa yes you can.

Comment: @njzk2 what do you mean?

Comment: @Rustam: I mean a lot of users of SO are not native English speakers, much less familiar with SMS spelling than you might be. For readability, it is asked from users to write in as proper English as possible.

Comment: @Rustam i wish i could. but i dont have reputation enough to vote up

Comment: @BrunoSousa i am not telling you for up vote. just accept answer if it clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [substrings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) and concatenation. You don't even need to use a `StringBuilder`.

```
String s = "70142012";
int pos = s.length()-4;
s = s.substring(0,pos) + "/" + s.substring(pos);
```

Comment: you should avoid `String` type object because it is `immutable`. i.e if you are modifying it's content it will create new `String`

Comment: here what is `i`? i think it should be `pos`.

Comment: @Rustam You're creating a new string anyway. That's a requirement of the question. The compiler is intended to perform this kind of string operation in an efficient way. (By the way, you were right about the typo - thanks for pointing it out)